# How to use a refinement to change the output of { now: Time.now }.inspect to be customized?

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching, refinements

After years of working with ruby, I finally came across a good need for ruby refinement!

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module TimeMongoInspect
  refine Time do

    def inspect
      strftime("Time.parse('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')")
    end

    def to_s
      strftime("Time.parse('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')")
    end
  end
end

using TimeMongoInspect

a = { time: Time.now }
puts a.inspect
```

The desired output is

```
{:time=>Time.parse('2023-08-29 00:39:08.546338569 +0000')}
```

In case someone is curious, I want to be able to cut-n-paste output into code, however, I need the date to be properly interpetted as a real Time class..

ChatGPT said to also refine Array and Hash

```rb
module TimeMongoInspect
  refine Time do
    def inspect
      "Time.parse('#{strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')}')"
    end

    def to_s
      inspect
    end
  end
  
  refine Hash do
    def inspect
      "{" + self.map { |k, v| "#{k.inspect}: #{v.inspect}" }.join(", ") + "}"
    end
  end

  refine Array do
    def inspect
      "[" + self.map { |v| v.inspect }.join(", ") + "]"
    end
  end
end
```

However, I thought this was making the problem even more complicated and was the wrong way to go.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that refinements are lexically scoped.

Meaning they apply only to code you write in the same script.

If you refine `Time#inspect`. Every call to `Time#inspect` from the same file/script will use your refined method.

If you call `Time.now.inspect` directly you will see that.

However, the refinement has no effect on code not in your script. For example `Hash#inspect` is not defined in your code. It's defined elsewhere that does not have your refinement. Therefore any `Time#inspect` called from there does not use your refinement.

Your options:

- Also redefine `Hash#inspect` and if you want `Array#inspect` in your refinement and live with the complexity.
- Redefine `Time#inspect` globally without refinements and live with the side-effects.